# How to simulate smaller iPhone screen size without simulator?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have an `iPhone 6 Plus` but I don't have an `iPhone 6`.
Because my app uses iPhone's music library, iPhone simulator of Xcode can not be used to run my app.

So, I want to run my app on my `iPhone 6 Plus` using `iPhone 6`'s screen size.

If I can simulate `iPhone 6`'s screen size on `iPhone 6 Plus`, I can test my app of `iPhone 6`'s screen size and also I can take screenshots of `iPhone 6`'s screen size for iTunes Connect.

Is there an easy way to simulate iPhone 6 screen on an iPhone 6 Plus device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is no way to do it. The best thing you can do is to remove music lib from the project, comment out the related code and do some screenshots on Xcode emulator.